# How does one present a modal view using PhoneGap?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, modalviewcontroller

Having made a few iOS apps, I'm now taking my first steps in building a HTML5 app with PhoneGap.

One of the things that has stumped me is how to present a modal view. In iOS it's trivial:

```
[myViewController presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

But after a bit of Googling, and checking out [PhoneGap's API reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/index.html), I can't find a single example of how to present a modal view...something I thought would be a trivial task with 100s of tutorials.

Or maybe I'm just really bad at Googling! I think however, that I'm missing something blindingly obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no presentModalViewController for phonegap, in phonegap you load all your code in a "webView", and all the code and page transitions have to be done with html+css+javascript, so you have to create your own flip, crossdisolve and other animations (or use jquery mobile, jqtouch, jqmobi or any other javascript framework with this animations), so you can reuse the code in other platforms, you don't have presentModalViewController on android or blackberry.

If you really want to use presentModalViewController on a iOS phonegap app, you have to create a plugin, or use phonegap as a component, then you create different views, loading different html files on them, and change betweem them with native code.

Comment: Ah. That's good to know. I would have thought that PhoneGap would have abstracted transitions. So that if you want to, say, slide up a view from below, you would go navigator.presentModalView('myView');

Comment: Okay, seems like jQTouch is the way to go for presentation stuff like transitions.

Comment: There are other alternatives to jQTouch, like jqUI (for jqmobi), sencha touch, jquery mobile, kendo UI, iUI, iWebkit. try some demos

Comment: Ah, yup, having a look at Sencha Touch now. Okay, all falling into place now, thanks jcesar.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog

Comment: Works perfect on iPad with PhoneGap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I much rather use bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

> $('#myModal').modal('show')