# target= _blank not working in iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, cordova

I am building a `phonegap` application which has to display an external terms & conditions page if the user clicks on the T&C link in the app. This page has to be opened in a new window and the user should be able to navigate back to the app after visiting this page.  My application works fine in **Android** and **Blackberry** devices. But in **iPhone** the 'terms & conditions' page opens in the same window and the user is not able to navigate back to the app. If the user closes the app(by pressing the centre button) and open it again, the same 'terms & conditions' page is displayed and the user is unable to proceed to the next page. Please find the code snippet below.

```
<a href="t&c url here" id="tc_url" target="_blank">
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You could do a modal dialog (e.g. HTML-based) - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341671/how-does-one-present-a-modal-view-using-phonegap) may have some relevant details

Answer (score 1):

You can open your page in InAppBrowser, use this .

```
var ref = window.open(url, 'random_string', 'location=no');

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
     console.log(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {

});
```